# About the haunted house in the beginning of Bly Manor series

Tags: the-haunting-of-bly-manor

In the TV series, The Haunting of Bly Manor, the very first episode introduces us to a group of people doing wedding rehearsals in a house. Apparently, that house is also haunted. As stated in [Vulture.com](https://www.vulture.com/article/haunting-of-bly-manor-recap-episode-1-the-great-good-place.html),

> The series premiere opens in 2007 at a purportedly haunted castle in
> Northern California, where a group of guests is drinking on the eve of
> a young couple’s wedding.

The dialogues are as follows:

> Bride: "We actually refused to stay here"
>
> Bridegroom: "She refused"

After bridegroom mentions that they would stumble upstairs in the house:

> Bride: "No way, not after those stories"

Then there is a mention of seeing "her" or a "dead woman" or "nun". The bride says if she did see something she wouldn't be getting married there.

**What is this house? Is this Hill house or Bly manor? Or is it a house that is being teased for the next season? What was the intention of putting the characters in one haunted house to show the story of another? (I am assuming choice of convenience)**

Comment: Have you finished the series?

Comment: Yes and if you mean to say that it's Dani's hand on the narrator's shoulder (in the very last episode), then does it confirm that they are in Bly Manor?

Comment: Bly Manor is in England. I imagine the wedding castle was chosen to set a spooky initial atmosphere and to give the narrator an excuse to tell a ghost story.

Comment: I agree with @Kitkat, along with the fact that it's rather ironic given whom the bride and some of the guests are -- There may also be other significance, as 'Bly Manor' is a pastiche of Henry James works woven together, but I have not read them all to conclude if there is a reference there in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure of what the house is supposed to be, but it is not Bly. Bly was in England, while the wedding is occurring in Northern California. It's also unlikely to be Hill House, as the family made sure nobody ever entered the building after what their family experienced. There are a few well known haunts in California, as well as the Haunting series being based on fictional hauntings. (The term fictional here meaning not based on a real place. I'm not commenting on the truth of hauntings as a whole.)

Answer (score 0):

The house where the wedding is held is definitely not Hill House or Bly Manor nor it does have any canon relation to them. It is likely to be a random house that is supposedly wrapped around with ghost stories. I doubt that this house will have a tie to the next season because this is an anthology series.

I don't know about the house, but the narration of this story to a group of people in a wedding is significant because

> the bride and her family are the ones who lived in the Bly Manor. The narrator used to be the groundskeeper of Bly Manor. So the narrator is essentially telling a story that's related to the bride's childhood.

The house's location is mentioned as Northern California, although the [actual house used for this is the **Cecil Green Park House at the University of British Columbia in Vancouver**](https://www.atlasofwonders.com/2020/10/the-haunting-of-bly-manor-house-location.html) and is famous for weddings and special events.